# React useState not updating onclick event with <Link>

Tags: reactjs, routes, onclick, components

I unable to update the state of the variable in ReactJS on click of . It's works fine without route but when I add to="/myUrl" It isn't working below is my code

```
const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("Home");
  const updatePageTitleText = (newValue) => {
    setPageTitle(newValue);
  };
```

Routing List

```
 <div>
 <ul>
    <li>
      <Link onClick={() => updatePageTitleText("Home")} to="/">
        Home
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link onClick={() => updatePageTitleText("About")} to="/about">
        About
      </Link>
    </li>
    <li>
      <Link onClick={() => updatePageTitleText("Services")} to="/services">
        Services
      </Link>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and find my component

```
 <Toolbar pageTitleProps={pageTitle} />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach is to use the useLocation hook and remove the onClick event from Link, like this:

```
        import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
        import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
        const [pageTitle, setPageTitle] = useState("Home");
        let location = useLocation();
        useEffect(() => {
                updatePageTitleText(location);
            }, [location]);
        const updatePageTitleText = (newValue) => {
            setPageTitle(newValue);
        };
        <Link to="/">
            Home
        </Link>
```